# Service -- best place to declare static strings for Shared Preferences

Tags: android, string, service, static, sharedpreferences

In a persistent Android Service, what's the best place to declare static strings to reference SharedPreferences, for eventual use in BroadcastReceivers?

```
public final static String KEY_ENABLE_LOCKSCREEN = "key_enable_lockscreen";
```

Declare them in the:

1. Service?
2. Activity?
3. A singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton!
It is way more clean that way.
Usually I declare mine in package names  utils.

```
mycustom.package.com.utils
```

Here a example.

```
public class MyUtility{
    public final static String KEY_ENABLE_LOCKSCREEN = "key_enable_lockscreen";
}
```

And when you use it , just refer to it everywhere as follows:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( MyUtility.KEY_ENABLE_LOCKSCREEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: You instantiate the Singleton in the Service constructor or onCreate()?

Comment: A singleton instantiates itself on first use, usually.

Comment: How does this assist in providing access in xml such as:<PreferenceScreen android:key="blah_blah"> ? I think you end up typing the constant value again ("blah_blah").

Answer (score 1):

Its better approach & practice to create a separate classes like

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.comapnyname.projectname.utility;

/**
* @author Rakesh.Jha
* All static member variable will be listed here
*/
public class MyPreferences {

    /*
     * @Declare all static variables here   
 */
    public final static String KEY_ENABLE_CODE = "0001";

}
```

When ever you want to use preferences you can use like -

```
MyPreferences.KEY_ENABLE_CODE
```

So, it will give you managed code to make speedness in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can extend `Application` class to create your own and declare it there.
2. You can create a helper class and just declare it in there. Your constant doesn't require a `Context` so it can safely live in there. This class doesn't have to be a singleton to hold your static final variable as it doesn't have to have an instance.

From [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) on `Application` class:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.
>
> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when first constructing the singleton.

Please note that this question is a bit opinion based and there's no one good answer.

Comment: For #2, is there a reason to create a Helper class versus just declaring them in the Service itself?  Would it just be for clarity?

Comment: Yes, really just for clarity and code organization. A `static final` can be declared pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to declare them in anything other than a static class. They're constants, really. You're not going to change them (as demonstrated in the example). Why bother instantiating them in a singleton? A static class just acts like a header file in C. An even better trick is to put them in an *interface* definition. That way, you can mix and match constants by implementing multiple interfaces in a class. When you implement an interface that doesn't have any methods, you inherit the constants.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to put such constants in the service as final static strings, with the minimum required scope (e.g. package private, or public, as required).

- **The singleton is completely unnecessary** (there is no need for an instance).
- **A separate utils class is unnecessary.** This may be a matter of preference, but there is very little to gain from having your constant definitions separated from the class they're related to. They can be accessed just as easily from the service as they can from some other arbitrary class, and in the long run I feel it will be easier to remember where the constants for MyService are, if they are in MyService, than if they are in some other utils class which you must now also remember the name of.
- **A separate utils class complicates naming**. Putting all of your constants in a single separate class will also require you to decorate the names, assuming you have multiple services/broadcasts. In other words, you won't be able to unambiguously use the same name for your constants in multiple services.

For example, I feel this:

```
public class PlaylistManager extends IntentService {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ERROR = "@package.name@.PlaylistManager.broadcast.ERROR";
    // can be referenced within this class as BROADCAST_ERROR

    private void broadcastError() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if(broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_ERROR);
            // etc.
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}

public class AudioCacheLoader extends IntentService {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ERROR = "@package.name@.AudioCacheLoader.broadcast.ERROR";
    // can also be referenced within this class as BROADCAST_ERROR

    private void broadcastError() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if(broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_ERROR);
            // etc.
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}

// naming pattern:
// PlaylistManager.BROADCAST_ERROR
// AudioCacheLoader.BROADCAST_ERROR
// etc.
```

...is more desirable than this:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static final String PLAYLIST_MANAGER_BROADCAST_ERROR = "@package.name@.PlaylistManager.broadcast.ERROR";
    public static final String AUDIO_CACHE_LOADER_BROADCAST_ERROR = "@package.name@.AudioCacheLoader.broadcast.ERROR";
}

public class PlaylistManager extends IntentService {

    private void broadcastError() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if(broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(MyUtils.PLAYLIST_MANAGER_BROADCAST_ERROR);
            // etc.
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}

public class AudioCacheLoader extends IntentService {

    private void broadcastError() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if(broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(MyUtils.AUDIO_CACHE_LOADER_BROADCAST_ERROR);
            // etc.
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}

// naming pattern:
// MyUtils.PLAYLIST_MANAGER_BROADCAST_ERROR
// MyUtils.AUDIO_CACHE_LOADER_BROADCAST_ERROR
// etc.
```

Note that the first example makes it easier to copy and paste code between service classes.

Also, keep in mind that you should use unique strings for BroadcastReceivers, unless you're using `LocalBroadcastManager`.

> The Intent namespace is global. Make sure that Intent action names and other strings are written in a namespace you own, or else you may inadvertently conflict with other applications.

(See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)